# How to properly clean in a Makefile?

Tags: makefile, find

For small C/C++ projects I am used to write my clean target as follow:

```
clean:
    $(RM) *.o *~
```

For slightly bigger projects, when sources are dispatched in subdirectories, say `src1` and `src2`, I would write

```
clean:
    $(RM) src1/*.o src1/*~ src2/*.o src2/*~
```

With even more subdirectories, it quickly becomes messy… So I realized I could use the `find` command like this:

```
clean:
    find . -name "*.o" -exec $(RM) {} \;
    find . -name "*~"  -exec $(RM) {} \;
```

However I saw that people often use `find` in conjunction with `xargs` instead of using `-exec` and I wonder why since it seems to work fine…

**What do you use and why?**

I know that for big projects, or for better compatibility, I should probably use cmake or autotools but I like the simplicity of a Makefile for small projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `exec` creates one sub-process per file being deleted. `xargs`, on the other hand, batches them up.

It's effectively the difference between:

```
rm src1/a.o
rm src1/b.o
rm src2/c.o
```

and:

```
rm src1/a.o src1/b.o src2/c.o
```

It's probably not going to matter that much unless you have a *lot* of files but it's worth knowing for that use case.

But I don't use *either* of those methods. I make each directory responsible for building itself (and it's subordinate directories), by having a Makefile in there. Then, from the top level make, I have something like:

```
all:
    for i in module1 module2 \
    do \
        cd $i \
        $(MAKE) all \
        cd .. \
    done
```

Same deal for the `clean` target. I *don't* assume that cleaning is the same action for every single subdirectory.

By doing that, the relevant actions are localised. If I have a directory where `.o` files are actually third party objects for me to link with (so I don't have the source), I make sure that `clean` won't delete them in that relevant makefile. The solution you have would hose them, causing much angst and gnashing of teeth :-)

Comment: GNU and BSD `find` support an extension to `-exec` that causes them to apply as many arguments to the command as possible: `find ... -exec ... +`

Comment: Nice too! Is there a good reason to use `cd …` -> `make` instead of `make -C …`?

Answer (score 3):

The version of 'find' I'm used to (GNU find) also supports a '-delete' flag.  I might do something like:

```
clean:
    find . -name '*.o' -delete
```

because it's effective, simple and clean.

If I have multiple patterns to delete, I normally repeat the command:

```
clean:
    rm -f a.out
    find . -name '*.o' -delete
    find . -name '*~' -delete
```